# Blue J Java Print string specified by int val

Tags: java, bluej

How do I print a string multiple times specified by an Int val.

say for instance

```
int value = 5;

print("?")
```

basically need to make the question mark print 5 times.
The int value can change. Just some homework i needed help on,
thanks

Comment: Your text book, would help you lot more!

Comment: You need to learn programming concepts from beginning. Refer some textbook.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i<value; i++) {
    //print("?")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use loop

```
int value = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
    System.out.println("something");
}
// at the end of code `value` is 5
```

or you can use `while`, but notice the difference that `value` variable always decremented here :

```
int value = 5;
while (value > 0) {
    System.out.println("something");
    value = value - 1;
}
// at the end of code `value` is 0
```